# Regex: text between first occurrence of two patterns

Tags: regex

```
/url?q=http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(film)&sa=U&ei=iavVUKuFGsrNswbz74GQBA&ved=0CBYQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEth5YspFPWp6CInyAfknlEvVgIfA
```

I need to get just

```
http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(film)
```

I tried with `\?q=(.*)&`
but it consider last occurrence of `&`, so I get

```
http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(film)&sa=U&ei=iavVUKuFGsrNswbz74GQBA&ved=0CBYQFjAA
```

http://rubular.com/r/yBiGIMQTUV

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use *reluctant matching* to match till the first `&`. With *greedy matching* (i.e. using `*` instead of `*?`), your pattern will match as long string as possible so as to satisfy the complete pattern.

So use this: -

```
\?q=(.*?)&
```

Or you can also use character class with negated `&` which matches every character except `&`: -

```
\?q=([^&]*)
```

Note that, if you don't want your `(.*?)` to match empty string, then you should use `+` quantifier. It matches `1 or more` occurrence.

Comment: Why when a complemented character class does the job -- and is more efficient?

Comment: @fge.. Yeah, I have given that option also. Preferrable I like that way too.

Comment: Would be nice to know what's more efficient, but I don't think that `([^&]*)` would be more efficient that just doing it lazy.

Comment: @JavierDiaz.. I don't think that would affect much on the efficiency. Because there would be no back-tracking in both cases. It's just the taste of an individual. Whatever fits to your style go with it. Readability is the major concern.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to make the `*` operator lazy, and you do it by adding a `?` after it. So it would be `.*?`

Lazy (or non greedy) means that will stop after the first occurrence of that match, instead of the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
\?q=([^&]+)
```

and capture the first group.

Answer (score 0):

If your in python then `sub(r'(\/url\?q\=)|[&][\S]*','',url)` should do your work